# Android : Add row into Google Spread Sheet

Tags: android, google-sheets

I use the following code to **add a list row**, it successful. But it looks like complex.

```
SpreadsheetService service =
    new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

// Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

// TODO Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.

/*
In Here, Instead of request all spread sheets,
I want to request only my spread sheet which I have stored on Google Drive.
*/

SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
    SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
  // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
}

SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

// Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
// TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
// app's needs.
WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
    spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

// Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

// Create a local representation of the new row.
ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("firstname", "Joe");
row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("lastname", "Smith");

// Send the new row to the API for insertion.
row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
```

And now, I want to be simple.

**Instead of request all spread sheets,
I want to request only my spread sheet which I have stored on Google Drive.**

I have the link of file spread sheet, docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=**KEYOFFILE**#gid=0.

Please tell me how,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, 
I fix it myself.

Instead use

```
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
```

We use :

```
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/KEYOFTHEFILE/private/full")
```

Thanks,

Comment: can we add row without auth2

Comment: Yes. You need key of file.